# Object.defineProperty not recognising getter or setter syntax

Tags: javascript

Consider the code below :

```
"use strict";

var obj = {
    firstName : "abhay",
    lastName : "Deol"
};


Object.defineProperty(obj, "fullName" , {

    get fullName(){
        return this.firstName + this.lastName;
    },

    set fullName(value){
        let words = value.toString().split(' ');
        this.firstName = words[0];
        this.lastName = words[1];
    },

    enumerable : true,
    configurable : true
});

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,"fullName"));
obj.fullName = "good boys"; // Error
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'fullName' of object '#<Object>'
    at Object.<anonymous> 
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

It seems it is not able to recognise the setter. Also, if I try to get value, it gives me `undefined`. This shows, getter also not getting recognised. But why?

In above code, it is recognising it as a data property and not as accessor property. Clearly syntax for getter/setter it is not accepting in descriptor object. But why ? This can be proved by output of this-

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,"fullName"));
```

as

```
{
  value: undefined,
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
}
```

The syntax I used in the code for getter/setter , works fine if I would have used it inside an object literal, so why fail for descriptor object? What I mean is that below is acceptable but above code syntax is not !

```
var obj = {

    firstName : "abhay",
    lastName : "Deol",

    get fullName(){
        return this.firstName + this.lastName;
    },

    set fullName(value){
        let words = value.toString().split(' ');
        this.firstName = words[0];
        this.lastName = words[1];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct syntax:

```
get fullName(){}
```

You need to define the keys `get` and `set` on the object such that `descriptorObject.get()` and `.set()` are callable. You are defining getters and setters for the property `fullName` on the descriptor object — but `definedProperty()` isn't looking for `fullName`.

Per MDN:

> An accessor descriptor also has the following optional keys:
>   get ...
>   set ...

The object you are passing, does not define these key.

Try using just:

```
get(){}
set(v){}
```

For example:

```js
"use strict";

var obj = {
    firstName : "abhay",
    lastName : "Deol"
};


Object.defineProperty(obj, "fullName" , {
    get(){
        return this.firstName + this.lastName;
    },

    set(value){
        let words = value.toString().split(' ');
        this.firstName = words[0];
        this.lastName = words[1];
    },
    enumerable : true,
    configurable : true
});

console.log(obj, obj.firstName)
obj.fullName = "good boys"; 
console.log(obj, obj.fullName)
```

Comment: Thnx Mark but my question is *why is my syntax wrong*. i already knew by your way it would work. The syntax I used in the code, works fine if I would have used it inside an object literal, so why fail for descriptor object?

Comment: @Number945 `get` and `set` are keys on the descriptor. You need to defined those keys with functions. You are trying do define a getter and setter for the object being passed in - you end up defining getter/setter for `fullName` which leaves the keys `get` and `set` undefined.

Comment: Then why is [this](https://jsbin.com/citihazuru/1/edit?js,console) acceptable syntax there? Your reasoning should apply here too. I have posted in question above the property descriptor. Please have a look. You will see, it will take it as data property! and not even accessor property.

Comment: Yes, that works because it's not being passed to `definedProperty` It sets a getter/setter for the key `fullName`. `definedProperty` is not going to look for that property. It is going to look for, and try to call, `get()` and `set()`. The object in the link you posted has no property `get` or `set`. Try calling `obj.get()` in the linked code — that's what `defineProperty` will try to do.